# How to add custom indicator using trading-vue-js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trading-vue-js library doesn't support Bollinger bands %B indicator, how to create a custom indicator to display it? Currently I think maybe I can use RSI indicator, but do the calculation by myself, change the name to "BB %B", and change 70 to 1(overbought), 30 to 0(oversold). But I am a newbie, I don't know how to do it, if anyone knows how to do it, I will be grateful.

Maybe I need to change something in the settings, but I don't know what to do

```js
offchart: [
    {
        name: "RSI",
        type: "RSI",
        data: [],
        settings: {
            // Any settings for the RSI indicator
        },
    },
    {
        name: "BB %B",
        type: "RSI",
        data: [],
        settings: {
            // Any settings for the RSI indicator
        },
    },
]
```

Thanks in advance!